# Preg_split all rows in table in a database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, preg-split

Hi guys so my code is down below. I'm using preg_split to display a string as an array using commas as my delimiter.

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("host","user","pw");
if (!$conn){
die("Can not connect: ".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("DB",$conn);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$mydata = mysql_query($sql,$conn);
$record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata);
$pattern = '/[,]/';
$string = $record['Components'];
echo '<pre>', print_r(preg_split($pattern,$string),1), '</pre>';


?>
```

So this code separates my entries in column Components by commas. But it only does so on the first row.

As Shown:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sedan
    [1] =>  Coupe
)
```

My question is how can I do this to all rows in column Components?

Comment: normalize the db, then this wont be an issue

Comment: database fetch calls only return a SINGLE row of results. if you want all the rows, you'll need a loop.

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). They are not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Answer (score 1):

Like what Dagon said, I just needed a loop to check all rows in my table. I just needed a while loop and put mysql_fetch_array inside it.

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata))
{
$pattern = '/[,]/';
$string = $record['Components'];
echo '<pre>', print_r(preg_split($pattern,$string),1), '</pre>';
}
```